# .NET, Silverlight and SQL Server 2008 - writing server side for the cloud

Tags: .net, sql-server, silverlight, cloud

I'm toying with the idea of embarking on a cloud-based client/server spare-time project using .NET, SQL Server and a client in Silverlight with google protobuffers as a serialization layer in order to learn more about these technologies. I have plenty of client/server experience but so far have not developed a scalable server application to deploy seamlessly in 'the cloud'

I know this question is short (and perhaps vague) but I would appreciate any pointers to resources of how to develop for scalability in .NET/Silverlight, specifically what caveats I should be aware of from the outset and how to test the scalability of my application.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw Mike Benovich at a conference and he gave a Win 7 phone Azure talk that had a lot of code. I couldn't find info on [his page](http://www.benkotips.com/) , but found a link of a [video](http://www.bhnetug.org/main/Events/PastMeetings/October2011.aspx). He was very open to being contacted and talked about having times where he would be available to answer questions about Azure.

Comment: Thanks that's interesting info. I actually need to run an AMQP message broker in this app. I read that RabbitMQ supports Amazon EC2 but not sure about Azure. Still these are the sorts of questions that could be directed at the Azure team themselves. Cheers!